# Pool Party Event Points

Tags: league-of-legends

I was searching around but I didn't find any information about that.

Is there any place where I can check the Pool Party Event Points I've already earn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot see how many points you've contributed, only the total amount of points collected. You can view the total [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/page/features/team-up-pool-party)